# In GXT, after changing the color of ContentPanel header color ,the vertical alignment of heading text goes to top. How to make it middle?

Tags: css, gwt, gxt

**In GXT**, after changing the color of ContentPanel header and size,the vertical alignment of heading text  goes to top. How to make it middle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set the positioning directly with GXT. However, what you can do is set that through CSS. You will need to set a `line-height` style to your heading text that is equivalent to the new height of your header. For example:

```
contentPanel.setHeadingHtml("<span style=\"line-height:125px\" >Test Heading</span>");
```

Technically, the style should be applied via a CSSResource style but that is a whole different topic.

Comment: Thanks, but still alignment is not changing.

Comment: I tried in CSS using vertical-alignmnt:middle but its not affected on alignment.

Comment: Vertical alignment only works in tables. Can you post some code so I can take a look?

Comment: contPanel.getHeader().setHeadingStyle("headerstyle");   In CSS  vertical-alignment:middle;

Comment: color:#003399;                                            background-color:#CFDAEB ;